# Deleted files keep reapearing on desktop after sorting

Tags: windows-10, desktop, trash

I have been doing a lot of work on my desktop recently, but since I like a nice clean desktop I have deleted all the files after I am done with them. Since I like to have my desktop icons sorted from A-Z, and there is now space, I sort them from A-Z. After doing this, without fail (as well as on my second PC), the deleted file has reappeared.

The file is 0 bytes in size and can be moved around, but any other attempt to interact with it results in an error message saying the file is no longer located there. How can I remove this icon, and how can I prevent this from happening?

The files seem to disappear off the desktop after 30-45 min as well.

I am running the latest version of windows as well as the newest drivers.

Comment: What's it called? [I have a bet laid for desktop.ini, but I'm prepared for it not to be… ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin They were three different files. One a "New Folder" folder, another a zipped folder called "Oculus_Logs..." and the final one was an executable (can't remember the extension) named "rename".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the desktop.ini because that is larger than 0 bytes.

You may open an elevated command prompt, and run `cd "%Userprofile%\desktop"` and then `del filename.ext` or omit `ext` if it doesn't have any extension. Use `rd /s "\\?\C:\users\%username%\Desktop\foldername "` if it is a folder. And also try to hide it using `attrib +h filename.ext` and make sure you have unchecked view hidden files/folders in Folder options.

Comment: Unchecking and rechecking the view hidden folders option fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open **Command Prompt** and delete the file that way.

- Open **Command Prompt** by right-clicking your start menu and clicking **Run**.
- Type `cmd` and press `enter`
- Navigate to your desktop folder by typing `cd Desktop` and pressing `enter`
- Delete the file you want by typing the `del` command followed by a space than then the file's full name and extension.

For example if my file was named "notes.txt" I would type `del notes.txt`and then I would press `enter`.

Verify that the file was deleted by either refreshing the desktop or sorting the desktop icons.

Comment: What about the public Desktop that gets merged with your own?  As in (usually) C:\Users\Public\Desktop.

Comment: Entering the command resulted in an error saying there was no such file, and after refreshing the desktop nothing changed.

Comment: In that case I would go with the recommendation by @SeñorCMasMas to check your public Desktop folder as well. Navigate there with `cd C:\Users\Public\Desktop` and use the same `del` commands. You can also use the `dir` command to see if the files are listed in the folder.